# Error in querying Google Analytics data in BigQuery: 'Correlated aliases referenced in the from clause must refer to arrays that are vali..'

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have created the following query from a BigQuery partitioned table, with as initial source Google Analytics-data. The goal is to get # sessions, product revenue and shipping costs. Note that in the current setup I can't use the 'aggregated' fields like totals.visits.

```
SELECT c_country AS country, date As Date,  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(Visitid AS STRING), CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))) AS Sessions, 
(SELECT SUM(product.productRevenue)/1000000 FROM t.hits as hits, hits.product AS product) AS Product_Revenue, (SELECT SUM(hits.transaction.transactionShipping)/1000000 FROM t.hits AS hits) AS Shipping_Costs
FROM `xx.yy.zz` as t
WHERE c_date BETWEEN "2019-11-06" AND "2019-11-06"
GROUP BY c_country, date
```

Now, the following error message appears:

> "Correlated aliases referenced in the from clause must refer to arrays
>   that are valid to access from the outer query, but t refers to an
>   array that is not valid to access after GROUP BY or DISTINCT in the
>   outer query at [2:50]"

Does anyone know how to adjust the query so that the query executes without issues?

Comment: shouldn't it be GROUP BY country, Date?

Comment: No, it's a custom partitioned table, that has the same structure as the regular GA BQ (sharded) tables, but some custom fields have been added, e.g. c_country.